# Why does this limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the limit of the limit

[Multivariable limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5wRh.gif)
I guess this limite doesn't exist.

I tried the path:
**y = x**

The result is 0.

Then I tried the path: **y = x²**

The result is **1/5**.

But the Wolfram Calculator tells me that the result is 0.

Why? The result from the paths are different. So, this limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, don't use Wolfram :))) If limit exists, it must be calculated from all paths with the same value. You are right, it doesn't exist.

Comment: this is not a proof, but polemic, but yes the Limit doesn' exist

Comment: $\epsilon-\delta$ method can be produced for wrong path, and this is will be proof.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was solving by myself and checking the result in the Wolfram calculator. But in this case, the result is different and now I'm not going to trust 100%. haha.